# MySQL procedimiento con clausula where variable

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedure

Buenos días/tardes/noches a todo el mundo!!

Tengo una consulta la cual no se buscar así que si alguien sabe un hilo que me lo pase.
La consulta es la siguiente, tengo un procedimiento almacenado donde le paso 3 variables, la cual vIdFiltro puede ser 0, en el caso de que sea 0 quiero que no me la incluya en la clausula WHERE ya que eso hará que no me devuelva ningún resultado. Ejemplo:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `consultas`(IN `vDesde ` DATE, IN `vHasta ` DATE, IN `vIdFiltro` INT)    
BEGIN
      SELECT * FROM consultas WHERE fechaDesde >= vDesde AND fechasHasta <= vHasta AND filtro= vIdFiltro;
END
```

Y mi consulta es si hay alguna manera de evitar incluir "filtro= vIdFiltro" en el where sin tener que duplicar la consuta, de la siguiente manera:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `_consulta_prueba`(IN `vDesde` DATE, IN `vHasta` DATE, IN `vIdFiltro` INT) BEGIN
IF(vIdFiltro != 0) THEN
    SELECT * FROM consultas WHERE fechaDesde >= vDesde AND fechasHasta <= vHasta AND filtro= vIdFiltro;
ELSE 
    SELECT * FROM consultas WHERE fechaDesde >= vDesde AND fechasHasta <= vHasta;
END IF;END
```

Ya que mi consulta en realidad es mucho más compleja y tiene algunos JOIN y UNION ALL.

Saludos y gracias de antemano a las personas que me quieran ayudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algo como esto te podría servir.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `_consulta_prueba`(IN `vDesde` DATE, IN `vHasta` DATE, IN `vIdFiltro` INT) 
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM consultas 
    WHERE fechaDesde >= vDesde AND fechasHasta <= vHasta AND (filtro = vIdFiltro or vIdFiltro = 0 or vIdFiltro is null);
END
```

lo que hará es igualar el filtro en caso de que exista, sino existe entonces lo tomara como nulo, y solo hará la otra parte del where.

Aqui podrias modificar si el filtro es texto cambiar el 0 por comillas de esta manera.

```
(filtro = vIdFiltro or vIdFiltro = '' or vIdFiltro is null)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! ufff que tonto, yo estaba complicando porque buscaba una clausula IF para poner en el where....